# Using YQL to extract data from a page?

Tags: json, xpath, yql

In [this table](http://housing.byu.edu/offcampus/compdata/largeComplexes.php) how would I use YQL/Xpath to get all data members of the column "Complex"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is as follows:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://housing.byu.edu/offcampus/compdata/largeComplexes.php%22%20and%20xpath=%22/html/body/table[2]/tr/td[2]/table//tr[not%28contains%28@bgcolor,%278495A9%27%29%29]//td[1]//p%22
```

every Complex-member is enclosed with a `<p>`-tag